# Applying pandas Timestamp() call to each item of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy array which is composed of numpy.datetime64 values. I'd like to convert these to pandas Timestamps using pandas.Timestamp().

I could do an explicit for-loop like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
stamps = [pd.Timestamp(t) for t in my_arr]
```

but this isn't very efficient. I can use numpy's vectorize function to do something like this instead

```
stamper = np.vectorize(pd.Timestamp)
stamps = stamper(my_arr)
```

but the numpy documentation states that vectorize is mostly a convenience function and not intended for performance. Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Edit: Here are some timings from some of the solutions given:

```
%timeit stamper(my_arr)
%timeit my_arr.astype(pd.Timestamp)
%timeit np.array([pd.Timestamp(t) for t in my_arr])
%timeit pd.to_datetime(my_arr)

100 loops, best of 3: 7.04 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 82 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 16.8 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop
```

Seems that the .astype() is fastest, so I'll go with this. Thanks!

Comment: Won't `pd.DataFrame(my_arr).to_timestamp()` do what you want?

Comment: Ed, it doesn't seem to. When I tried this I got " 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'to_timestamp' "

Comment: Sorry try `pd.DataFrame(my_arr).to_timestamp(axis=1)`

Comment: Same problem. I'm using pandas 0.13.1, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is there a reason you specifically need TimeStamp? I think that if you just constructed a df from the np array the dtype will be preserved as datetime64 is that not enough?

Comment: The reason I was wanting Timestamp is that I later take some differences. The difference between Timestamps is a datetime.timedelta, which I can then ask for nice properties like .total_seconds(). If I take a difference of datetime64s I get a timedelta64, which leaves me still in the "how do I manipulate this strange object?!?" space.

Comment: Does it matter that one is timedelta and the other is timedelta64?

Comment: I want to be able to get seconds, minutes, etc. in a nice convenient way. I don't know that a timedelta64 has such easy methods.

Comment: you need to use ``pd.to_datetime(arr)``. but if you want to actually do useful things, you need a more modern pandas, e.g. >= 0.15.0 to handle the timedelta type things.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff. I'm using the Pandas in the Xubuntu distro I'm using, but I should consider installing it from the newest source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my_arr is a numpy ndarray, I would suggest doing :

```
my_arr.astype(pd.Timestamp)
```

That would create a copy of the array and cast it to the type you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use the vectorized function `pd.to_datetime()`.

Suppose your datetime string is not the standard ISO-format

```
my_arr = np.array(['8/28/2015 13:46', '8/27/2015 13:26', '8/27/2015 11:46'])
my_arr

array(['8/28/2015 13:46', '8/27/2015 13:26', '8/27/2015 11:46'], 
      dtype='<U15')
```

Call the vectorized function `pd.to_datetime()` with customized format argument

```
dts = pd.to_datetime(my_arr, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
dts

DatetimeIndex(['2015-08-28 13:46:00', '2015-08-27 13:26:00',
               '2015-08-27 11:46:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

You can calculate difference between different timestamps and total seconds

```
dts[0] - dts[-1]

Timedelta('1 days 02:00:00')

(dts[0] - dts[-1]).total_seconds()

93600.0
```